# Cucumber first scenario for blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

So for cucumber, I have a blank application.  I'm thinking about for my first BDD it should be:

```
Feature:  Blog
As an Owner
In order to retain customers
I want to create a blog

Scenario:  Add blog posts
Given I am logged in as owner
When I go to the blog
And I create a post
Then it should appear on the blog page
```

I feel like this isn't right.  I feel like the first scenario is the hardest, because after that adding a feature should be easier.

So what should the first scenario/Feature be?

Comment: For the feature that you have written, your scenario seems right to me. If you are looking for better answers make your question more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of the blog application in terms of the capabilities it delivers, here's what you're currently addressing:

- Logging in
- Writing blog posts
- Reading blog posts

That's a lot to deliver for just one scenario.

If this is just standard blogging software, then you could always start with the *purpose* of the software - presumably to attract users to your site. What if you just wrote posts by hacking the database with SQL? What if you didn't have any login? What if all you did was display blog posts?

Now you can start with a very much simpler scenario:

> Given my most recent blog post is titled "Unicorns are real"
>   When Ursula the unicorn collector sees my blog
>   Then the post should be visible on the first page.

Try to make it specific, rather than generic, as this will help you remember what you've already delivered as well as helping your imagination to come up with other scenarios.

The benefit of starting with this post is that you'll *only* record the things in the database that are actually needed to display a post (and you may decide to use a filesystem instead of a database, etc.)

After that, publishing posts and then logging in to do it will be much easier still.

If you're intending to display adverts, and link keywords to them, etc., then the purpose of your site is to make money, and I would write a scenario around that before you even worry about users coming to read the posts.

This is the advice I give *if* there's nothing unusual about your blog. However, if you're doing anything differently to the standard blogging software out there, I recommend focusing on that first, as it's where all the risk will be.

Comment: Thanks!!  This helps a lot.  I really want to get into BDD and TDD, but part of the problem is where do you start.  This clears things up on how specific I should be.